# Можно в terrain.terrainData.treeInstances поместить не деревья?

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

Мне надо создать кисть в которой будут камни, столбы, кусты и прочие элементы окружающей среды . Я купил кисть [Prefab Brush](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/prefab-brush-21321) . Но я хочу понять, возможно ли объекты которые я рисую на сцене этой кистью(Prefab Brush), добавить в terrainData.treeInstances как добавляют обычные деревья?

Возможно ли использовать для объекта класса TreeInstance, в качестве prefab-a не дерево?

Comment: Вряд ли кто-то будет покупать ассет, чтобы ответить на вопрос. Спросите напрямую у создателя кисти.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Здесь даже не надо покупать кисть. Я хочу понять можно в terrain.terrainData.treeInstances назначить префабы камней, столбов и другие элемнты окружающей среды? У меня в terrainData получается запехнуть пока префаб дерева только

Comment: Не работал с террейном в юнити, но не вижу никаких проблем засунуть в деревья префаб камня.